# Android: Reading a file: Does not open the first time I select the file. When I try it again it opens the file

Tags: android

So this is my code. What happens is that when I first launch the app, I try to select a file, and the resultCode is 0. The second time I click on the button to open the explorer, I select the file and the resultCode is -1 so it successfuly opens the file. Any idea what happens the first time? I cannot seem to understand why does it give me code 0? Thanks guys. P.S. This is awful coding but I am simply trying to understand the file opening procedures in Android. Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

final int ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button my_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity);
    my_button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("file/");
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.v("onActivityResult","requestCode is: " + requestCode + " resultCode" + resultCode);
    if ((requestCode == ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
        Log.v("onActivityResult","Passes through if statement");
        //String fileSelected = data.getStringExtra("fileSelected");

        String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
        TextView my_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        my_text.setText(FilePath);
        StringBuilder text = null;

        try{
            Scanner input = new Scanner(FilePath);
            //File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            //File yourFile = new File(dir, FilePath);

            //Read text from file
            text = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FilePath));
                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(line);
                    text.append('\n');
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                //You'll need to add proper error handling here
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.v("file not opened","THE FILE WAS NOT OPENED");
        }

        my_text.setText(text);
    }                   
}
}
```

Comment: Such errors are 3rd party errors , try to use the app on another device or the emulator and see how it goes

Comment: @Mr.Me, I tried different file explorers and they work just fine. Thanks for the explanation!. Please mark your post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such errors are 3rd party errors, try to use the app on another device or use the emulator and see how it goes.